# Unspecified GSS failure. after setting up krb5/ldap authentication

Tags: authentication, openldap, kerberos, centos7

new here, so I recently setup ldap/krb5 authentication on an centos7.2 vm. Krb5/ldap is working correclty as I can login using ldap user account. However, when I check the logs in the client machine `/var/log/secure` it is spamming `Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information, No credentials cache found`

It is not permissions issues on ~/.ssh and ~/.ssh/authorized_key.

Can anyone give me some pointers in how to troubleshoot this? Posts regarding this issue is all over google, but normally they are accompany by other errors, however `Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information, No credentials cache found` is the only error in the logs and it's making difficult for me to troubleshoot it.